# How can I reword this question to better fit programmers.se?

Tags: discussion, subjective

I have asked [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260192/why-does-fred-brooks-uses-this-quote-in-the-mythical-man-month?noredirect=1#comment527053_260192) because I wanted to know how and why F. Brooks connected this quotation, from a restaurant:

> Good cooking takes time. If you are made to wait, it is to serve you
>   better, and to please you.

with software engineering. I understand that it has a subjective theme, so tried to reword to better fit programmers.se following the guidelines on [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). However it seems like it didn't work, so I would like to ask for some tips (its better if you could give some examples) about how to improve the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, not sure that you can. This [meta post](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog) explains why they don't work well here.

Comment: @GlenH7 Ok, then the best option is to delete the question?

Comment: @gaboroncancio The person asking the question cannot delete it if it has an up voted or accepted answer.  You can flag it for a moderator to delete, or wait a few days for regular users with delete vote privileges to act upon it (20k rep can act on it immediately).

Answer (score 1):

Not all questions are a good fit for the StackExchange format.  That doesn't necessarily mean that it's a bad question.  It just means it doesn't fit.  And to answer your broader question, there isn't much (anything?) that can be done to salvage the question.

I noted your comment in the main question about deleting it.  The short answer is yes, it should be deleted as it doesn't help the site and it doesn't fit within the site's guidelines.

That said, because there are up voted answers on your question you don't have the ability to delete the post (as MichaelT also pointed out).  A few high rep users from the community have already cast delete votes and removed it.  You can still access the question if you have a direct link since you're the owner of the post.